# String to pathname Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, csv, path

I am attempting to read a csv column that contains a file path and move that file. I can iterate through the csv and take the object as a string. However when I make the call to move the file like this,

```
require 'csv'    
require 'fileutils'

CSV.foreach('file.csv', :headers => true) do |csv_obj|
  path = csv_obj['Filename'] 
  name = path.split('/')[2]
  dest = 'folder/'
  FileUtils.mv "#{path}", "#{dest}"
end
```

I get:

> fileutils.rb:1515:in `stat': No such file or directory - Spam/Jane April - 45 FAC (IDRI 2)/JaneA somewebsite 2014-03-25 040024 - IDRI.pdf (Errno::ENOENT)

In this file, the first iteration of the csv, `csv_obj` is

> "Spam/Jane April - 45 FAC (IDRI 2)/JaneA somewebsite 2014-03-25 040024 - IDRI.pdf"

Both the file and the destination folder exist. I think the error is with escaping characters. I tried using `Shellwords.escape`, `pathname` class, `system move`, and `rename`.

Comment: Is `Spam/Jane April - 45 FAC (IDRI 2)/JaneA somewebsite 2014-03-25 040024 - IDRI.pdf` relative to the current directory?

Comment: If `csv_obj` is that string, then what is `csv_obj['Filename']`?

Comment: Yes, this ruby file is sitting in the base directory where the Spam folder is. csv_obj is a string. I tried the below suggestion and I am still recieving the same error. name was originally for the rename the file attempt.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe escaping of characters is your problem. More than likely it's that the path is not correct relative to where you are running your ruby script. Try something like

```
# get the absolute path of your script's location
current_dir = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))

# get absolute path of your .pdf file
abs_path = File.join(current_dir, path)

if !File.exists?(abs_path)
    puts "#{abs_path} does not exist"
end
```